# If $P(A | B)=\frac{P(A\cap B )}{P(B)}$ and $P(A\cap B )=P(A)P(B)$ , then is not $P(A | B)=P(A)$?

Tags: probability

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition:

$$P(A | B)=\frac{P(A\cap B )}{P(B)}$$

and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability#Independent_events:

$$P(A\cap B )=P(A)P(B)$$

Do not the two above just imply

$$P(A | B)=P(A) \quad ?$$

Looking at [this example with the dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Example), how would you use the formulas to solve the final example

$$P(A=2 | A+B ≤ 5) ?$$

Comment: Didn't you miss the qualifier "independent" in the second link ? It is clearly stated. Conditional probabilities are precisely about probabilistic dependence/independence.

Comment: As the title on Wikipedia suggests, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ holds if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Otherwise it does not.

Comment: ok so what does the notion $$P(A\cap B )$$ stand for then? obviously not only independent events.

Comment: It's the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur, in any situation.

Answer (score 1):

As several comments point out, you are using a formula for **independent** events.
And you are proving
$$P(A|B)=P(A)$$
In English this is "The probability for A given B is the same as the overall probability for A."  And that is another way of saying that A is independent of B.

Comment: hehe well the wikipedia articles state that $$P(A\cap B )$$  is always $$P(A)P(B)$$ at least it made me think that. But back to my question, how would you solve the dice formula?

Comment: No, that is not what the wikipedia article states. Read it again.

Comment: i read it 10 times already.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cap B) = P(A) P(B) \iff$ $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Let $A = \{\text{Get Ace in first trial}\}, B = \{\text{Get an Ace in second trial}\}$.
Consider two scenarios.

1. You roll a fair die twice. What is the probability of rolling an an Ace (One) twice? Since the rolls are independent, then
   $$P(AB) = P(A)P(B) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}.$$
2. Draw two cards from a standard deck without replacement. What is that probability that you draw two Aces. Clearly, the second draw is dependent of the first. Thus
   $$P(AB) = P(A)P(B|A) = \frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{221}.$$

As for the dice problem referenced in the post, refer to table 3.
[image]
Since you are told that the outcome space has been reduced to the outcomes such that $A+B\leq 5$, you are only left with the options in dark gray (10). However, only 3 of these cases have $A = 2$. Thus
$$P(A = 2| A+B\leq 5) = \frac{3}{10}.$$

Comment: ok I can count the fields as well. But which formula was I supposed to use, say given $P(A=2)$ and given $P(A+B<=5)$

Comment: @Toskan I think you need to clarify your question a bit. I think you are asking $$P(A = 2|A+B\leq 5) = \frac{P(A = 2, A+B\leq 5)}{P(A+B\leq 5)} = \frac{P(A = 2, B\leq 3)}{P(A+B\leq 5)} =\frac{P(A = 2)P(B\leq 3)}{P(A+B\leq 5)} =\frac{3}{10}.$$ Doing it this way is using Bayes' Rule.

Comment: is there no other way aside from making your step 3 of your comment? it must be made independent?

Comment: @Toskan It's **always** independent. You can recognize that and explicitly write $P(A=2, B\leq 3) = P(A = 2)P(B\leq 3)$, or you can just reason the correct probability directly from $P(A=2, B\leq 3)$.

Comment: yes I see in this simple example. But it has always be made independent, otherwise you cannot solve it right?

Comment: @Toskan No, you can use reasoning/use logic and **keep** $P(A = 2,B\leq 3)$. Is that what you are asking? If you want to do that, you can, for example, draw a table of all 36 pairs $(a, b)$ and count the events that satisfy $A=2, B\leq 3$. There are $\frac{3}{36}$.

Comment: but exactly this step is the one that actually made it independent, no? $P(A=2,B≤3)$ is independent whereas $P(A=2,A + B≤5)$ is not? furthermore, the comma is there as _and_?

Comment: @Toskan Yes comma = 'and'. I see what you are saying. Sure, you can say that. Actually complete steps are like this. Remember that if $C$ and $D$ are independent, then $P(C|D) = P(C)$. Thus
$$P(A = 2, A+B \leq 5) = P(A=2)P(A+B\leq 5|A = 2) = P(A=2)P(2+B\leq 5|A = 2) = P(A=2)P(B\leq 3|A = 2) = P(A=2)P(B \leq 5)$$ where the last step is true since $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A=2\mid A+B\leq5)=\frac{P(A=2\wedge A+B\leq5)}{P(A+B\leq5)}=\frac{P(A=2\wedge B\leq3)}{P(A+B\leq5)}$$

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then: $$P(A=2\wedge B\leq3)=P(A=2)P(B\leq3)$$
Now get to work, I would say.

Comment: what is wrong with the formula $(6/36 + 10/36 - 3/36)/(10/36) = 1.3$ which in the example should be $P(A|B) = P(A or B)/P(B) = \frac{P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)}{P(B)}$ but the result should be 0.3

Comment: @Toskan The $\cap$ symbol means **and**. Thus, it should be$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A\text{ and }B)}{P(B)}.$$

Comment: so conditional probability must always be broken down in independent parts otherwise you cannot use the formula did i get it right? without your step 2 this wouldn't be solvable right? or at least, not straight forward

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are not given to be independent then it is not possible to calculate $P(A=2\mid A+B\leq5)$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent then it is possible, and the fact of independence is exploited in what you call step 2.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ is equivalent to $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ so long as $P(A \mid B)$ is actually defined, which it isn't when $P(B) = 0$.  Since we could be dealing with events that have probability zero we prefer the more general definition $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$.